# Spotfire 11.3: Compare column value to previous row

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-analyst

I have a table of data in Spotfire, and I'm trying to create a calculated column that compares the Top Depth in a row to the Top Depth in the previous row (rounded to the second decimal). I've searched around Google and came up with the following code:

```
CASE  
  WHEN 
    First([TOP DEPTH]) OVER (Intersect([UWI],[FORMATION],[SOURCE]))=First([TOP DEPTH]) OVER ([UWI],[FORMATION],[SOURCE]) THEN 
         "Same"
  Else "Different"
END
```

Here is the result:

| UWI | FORMATION | SOURCE | TOP DEPTH | ROW_CHANGED_DATE | Origin of data | Top in Both DBs | Different Top MD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SWD 5B1-36-722 | BIRDS_NEST | KPB | 3726.18 | 9/27/2022 8:39 AM | GGX | Yes | Same |
| SWD 5B1-36-722 | BIRDS_NEST | KPB | 3726.17799495722 | 2/28/2022 11:43 AM | KGDM | Yes | Same |
| SWD 5B1-36-722 | MAHOGANY | KPB | 4298.83 | 9/27/2022 8:39 AM | GGX | Yes | Same |
| SWD 5B1-36-722 | MAHOGANY | KPB | 4298.83061688323 | 2/28/2022 11:43 AM | KGDM | Yes | Same |
| SWD 5B1-36-722 | UT_GREEN_RIVER | KPB | 3338.89 | 11/2/2022 6:41 AM | GGX | Yes | Same |
| SWD 5B1-36-722 | UT_GREEN_RIVER | KPB | 3338.89269012779 | 2/28/2022 11:43 AM | KGDM | Yes | Same |
| SWD 7A1-35-722 | BIRDS_NEST | KPB | 3851.15 | 11/16/2022 12:46 PM | GGX | Yes | Same |
| SWD 7A1-35-722 | BIRDS_NEST | KPB | 3751.14809387324 | 2/28/2022 11:38 AM | KGDM | Yes | Same |
| SWD 7A1-35-722 | MAHOGANY | KPB | 4323.8 | 11/16/2022 12:40 PM | GGX | Yes | Same |
| SWD 7A1-35-722 | MAHOGANY | KPB | 4323.80061282113 | 2/28/2022 11:38 AM | KGDM | Yes | Same |
| SWD 7A1-35-722 | UT_GREEN_RIVER | KPB | 3363.86 | 11/16/2022 12:40 PM | GGX | Yes | Same |
| SWD 7A1-35-722 | UT_GREEN_RIVER | KPB | 3363.86278904381 | 2/28/2022 11:34 AM | KGDM | Yes | Same |

If you look at rows 7 and 8, they are being marked as having the same Top MD (or Depth), but they should be marked as different.

I cannot seem to find a decent location to site to get additional information on how to use the different expressions and functions. If someone could help me out on what should be an easy question, I would really appreciate it.

Also, if anyone has any suggestions on where to go to get more information on how to use the Spotfire expressions, I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can do it via an intermediate column, but according to your stated requirements, I would say the first value
in each group should be fixed (you decide either empty, or False, or True) because there is no previous row in that group to compare to.

Intermediate column: the row id
[id] calculated as

```
rowId()
```

Final column: if you want the first value to be empty

```
Round([TOP DEPTH],2)=Round(Last([TOP DEPTH]) over (Intersect(Previous([id]),[UWI],[FORMATION],[SOURCE])),2)
```

if you want the first value to be True:

```
SN(Round([TOP DEPTH],2)=Round(Last([TOP DEPTH]) over (Intersect(Previous([id]),[UWI],[FORMATION],[SOURCE])),2),True)
```

or False:

```
SN(Round([TOP DEPTH],2)=Round(Last([TOP DEPTH]) over (Intersect(Previous([id]),[UWI],[FORMATION],[SOURCE])),2),False)
```

On YouTube there is the Dr Spotfire series of videos, you should be able to find more information there.

Comment: Thanks, Gaia. I'll try this out and see if I can make it work. Thanks for the recommendation on the Dr Spotfire videos. I'll check them out. :)

Comment: Gaia, I tried all three of your solutions and none of them worked. The first one left the calculated column blank, the second one caused all of the rows to be labelled "Same" and the third one caused all of the rows to be labelled "Different".

Comment: strange, it worked for me with exactly the data you posted. It looks like the first is the one to fix (second and third would respectively substitute blank with True or False). Are there any differences in your data from the sample you posted?

Comment: I suggest you look for what pieces of the expression return separately to see when it generates a blank. E.g. check [id], then Round([TOP DEPTH],2), then check Last([TOP DEPTH]) over (Intersect(Previous([id]),[UWI],[FORMATION],[SOURCE])) etc

Comment: Will do. I have to head out to an appointment, but I'll let you know what I find later

Comment: I never could get this to work quite right, so I ended up recreating the table so that the two Top Depths were in their own columns